# Same end point returning application/pdf and application/json

Tags: java, spring-restcontroller

I have a method which returns a pdf. But if anything goes wrong, I want to send back the response in json format. I wrote following code for it -

```
@PostMapping(value="/pdf", produces = {"application/json", "application/pdf"}) 
ResponseEntity<Object> pdf(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {  
     try {
         File file = new File("test.pdf");
         return new ResponseEntity(file, HttpStatus.OK);
     } else {
         ErrorResponse errorResponse = ErrorResponse.builder().setMessage("Got some error").build();
         return new ResponseEntity(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
     }
}
```

Is this the correct and standard way to implement this? I found another way where I can convert file or errorResponse to byte[], change the return type of method to ResponseEntity<byte[]> and remove "application/pdf" from produces element of PostMapping but can't decide which one is better.